# ¿Por qué se setea por default el mismo valor en diferentes mat select dentro de un mat table?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-table

Tengo la siguiente tabla que se llena consumiendo a una api, el campo **esValido** me regresa valores 0 y 1, esos valores yo los quiero colocar dentro de un mat-select pero que al desplegarse la lista muestre los valores Si y No, para ello si el servicio me regresa valor 1 es Si, y si regresa valor 0 es No.

Para ello dentro del metodo obtenerLista() que me regresa el servicio itere para obtener el valor de ese campo y asignarlo a la variable **selected**, y dentro del console si muestra los valores que regresa 1 y 0, pero en mi vista siempre muestra la etiqueta No, y parece que no Toma el valor 1, para que muestre el Si

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="scrollme">
    <form>
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="idControl">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID.</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.idControl }}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="cveEstado">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ESTADO</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="select-css" [ngClass]="{'text-red': element.cveEstado=='ERR',
        'text-green': element.cveEstado=='INP', 'text-orange': element.cveEstado=='PEN'}">
            <mat-select [(value)]="element.cveEstado" (selectionChange)="cambiarEstado($event.value, element)"
              [disabled]="!element.editar">

              <mat-option *ngFor="let estatus of estadoModel" [value]="estatus.cveEstado"
                [disabled]="deshabilitarOpcion(element.cveEstado).includes(estatus.descripcion)">
                {{ estatus.descripcion }}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="comentario">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>COMENTARIO</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput [value]="element.comentario" (keyup)="changeValue($event.target, element)"
                [disabled]="!element.editar" />
            </mat-form-field>
            <br>
            <span class="error" *ngIf="element.limiteExcedido">El tamaño máximo es de 15 caracteres</span>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="horaInicio">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>HORA</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput [value]="element.horaInicio" (keyup)="changeValueHora($event.target, element)"
                [disabled]="!element.editar" />
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="fechaRegistro">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>FECHAREGISTRO</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill" *ngIf="element.fechaRegistro">
              <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [value]="element.fechaRegistro"
                (dateChange)="onDateChange($event.value, element)" [disabled]="!element.editar" />
              <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
              <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="esValido">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ES VALIDO </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <mat-form-field>
              <mat-select [(value)]="selected" >
                <mat-option value="1">Si</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="0">No</mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="botonSave">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>GUARDAR</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
            <button mat-button (click)="guardar(element)">Guardar</button>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10]" showFirstLastButtons aria-label="Select page of periodic elements">
    </mat-paginator>
  </div>
</div>
```

mi component.ts

```
selected:any;

//obtiene la lista del servicio
  dataSource: any;
  private obtenerLista() {
    this.controlService.obtenerLista().subscribe((response) => {
      this.control = response.data;

      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.control);
      this.dataSource.data.map((item: { esValido: any; }) =>{
        this.selected = item.esValido;
        console.log("datos   ",this.selected);
      })
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien me podría decir como corregirlo y que muestre la etiqueta correcta dependiendo el valor?

Comment: Probaste usando `[value]` en lugar de `[(value)]`?

Comment: si, ya tambien pero aun asi muestra la misma etiqueta para todos aunque su valor sea diferente

Comment: ¿Dónde ejecutas esa función? Dentro del constructor, ngOnInit, etc?

Comment: @René ya lo solucione, gracias, lo estaba intentando hacer de esa manera porque no me funcionaba el  [(value)] y usando el arreglo de valores 0 y 1 , pero era por el tipo de dato, en el servicio venia "1" y "0" y yo tenia 1 y 0

Answer (score 0):

Has metido un paréntesis de más

```
[(value)]="element.cveEstado"
```

De esa forma estás indicando que haga un binding de los datos.

tan solo borra el paréntesis

```
[value]="element.cveEstado"
```

Espero que te sirva.

Un saludo!